# I want to remove the bottom margin of the PIXI application

Tags: javascript, css, pixi.js

I would like to create an application using PIXI.js.
When I add a PIXI application to the DOM, there is a margin at the bottom.
[there is amargin at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlUem.png)

Can I remove the bottom margin?

[sample PIXI project](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-snow-1cog44)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a style with specific style for the canvas element:

```
<style>
    canvas {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

Here's the result:
[image]
Keep in mind this will make all canvas elements appear as block elements.